# After opening contact list how is it possible to get the phone number on Click?

Tags: android, android-studio, contacts

I have the following button in my code snippet.

```
 <Button
 android:text="Choose Contact"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/ContactButton"
 android:onClick="callContact"
 android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
 android:layout_above="@+id/CallButton"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

and I have the following method (which, as you see, is processed on Click):

```
   public void callContact(View v) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
   startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }
```

Now I see the contact list. I ask you howit is possible to get the number out of a contact if I click on it?

android-studio onclick android-contacts contact

Answer (score 0):

Try this Intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Need to call On Activity Result :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (data != null) {
    Uri uri = data.getData();

    if (uri != null) {
        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                    null, null, null);

            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                String mobileNumber = c.getString(0);
                int type = c.getInt(1);

            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                c.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul Kharade, thanks you your answer. I tried it out, but it crasher. Do you maybe know the possible reasons?

Comment: Its look like permission issue, add into manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

Comment: well, it is in, and it is still crashing. any other idea?

Comment: Please check above answer.